# Prelaunch task build terminated with exit code 1 when class header is included in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, vscode-debugger

I get this error `The Prelaunch task build terminated with exit code 1` in `VSCode` when I try to run a simple code using `MinGW`. I'm not familiar with `launch.json` and `tasks.json`. Is there anything wrong with them?

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mainn.hpp"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" <<std::endl;
    BA BankAccount;
    BankAccount.setAge(20);
}
```

`mainn.hpp`:

```
class BA{
    public:
        void setAge(int A);
        int age;
    private:
};
```

`mainn.cpp`:

```
#include "mainn.hpp"

void BA::setAge(int A){
    age = A;
}
```

`launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

`tasks.json`:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong with either. Are you trying to debug your program? That's what `launch.json` is for. But you need to compile all of your *.cpp files, and your `tasks.json` doesn't do that.

Comment: @sweenish is tasks.json for telling the compiler to compile .cpp files? Why this doesn't happen when I define the class inside the main.cpp and not separately?

Comment: It's stated in my previous comment. If you have multiple cpp files, they must all be compiled. Where in `tasks.json` does it do that? The answer is it doesn't. With VS Code, once you need multiple compilations, a build system is easier to deal with.

Comment: @sweenish Thanks for your answer. I think it's better to use the CMake Tools extension for VSCode instead of editing tasks.json in the case of my problem.